# Set a child's value after sorting from another child

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

What I want to do is pull the top 3 under `questsLeaderboard`, sorted by `score`, then replace the existing children in `questsTop` with these new top 3.

So if `questsLeaderboard` looks like:

```
- questsLeaderboard
  - uid1
    - score: 12
    ...
  - uid2
    - score: 3
    ...
  - uid3
    - score: 10
    ...
  - etc
```

And I want `questsTop` to look like:

```
- questsTop
  - first
    - score: 12
    ...
  - second
    - score: 10
    ...
  - third
    - score: 3
    ...
```

I have tried this:

```
export const updateBoards = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  let questsArr = [];
  const questsRef = db.ref('questsLeaderboard');
  const questsTopRef = db.ref('questsTop');


  questsRef.orderByChild('score').limitToLast(3).on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    questsArr.unshift(snapshot);
  });

  if (questsArr.length === 3) {
    questsTopRef.set({
      first: questsArr[0],
      second: questsArr[1], 
      third: questsArr[2]
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).send('top quests set');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    })
  }

})
```

But it gives a timeout error. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably use `on()` in Cloud Functions, since the listener will remain active. Also: what will happen with your code if there are fewer than 3 scores? The `if (questsArr.length === 3)` will never be true, and you'll never send a result back to the client.

You'll want to use a `once("value"` listener instead, like this:

```
export const updateBoards = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  let questsArr = [];
  const questsRef = db.ref('questsLeaderboard');
  const questsTopRef = db.ref('questsTop');


  return questsRef.orderByChild('score').limitToLast(3).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      questsArr.unshift(child);
    })
    return questsTopRef.set({
      first: questsArr[0],
      second: questsArr[1], 
      third: questsArr[2]
    })
    .then(() => {
      return res.status(200).send('top quests set');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    })
  });
})
```

You'll also note that I added `return` statements to all the asynchronous database operations, to ensure that Cloud Functions keeps your function alive until the read and write are finished. For more on this, see the [second example in this documentation section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result).

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've changed it to your answer but where it is doing `forEach` it is telling me `Argument of type '(child: DataSnapshot) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: DataSnapshot) => boolean'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.` Upon removing the forEach and just going with the `unshift(snapshot)`, I get an error in the console `Reference.set failed: First argument contains a function in property 'questsTop.first.node_.children_.comparator_' `

Comment: I just fixed a mistake in that loop (I should push `child` instead of `snapshot`). But I don't think that causes the error you have. I'm not sure where that error comes from.

Comment: Yeah, the `function` part of that forEach loop is underlined, so the error wasn't fixed :/. And I think there is an issue with setting questsArr[num] as a value.